# SwiftUI - Timing of views getting added to the window hierarchy when using a List

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm creating a SwiftUI app for iPhone and iPad which starts out with a list. Each entry represents a different view the user can transition to. Each view could use an explanation, so I'd like to show one the first time the user navigates to them. I'm trying to use `fullScreenCover` to show this "intro view".

But when the full screen cover tries to show I get the following, and hence the intro view never shows:

```
2020-10-22 09:55:05.587361-0700 test[81095:3217286] [Presentation] Attempt to present
<_TtGC7SwiftUI22SheetHostingControllerVS_7AnyView_: 0x7f883e51bcc0> on
<_TtGC7SwiftUI41StyleContextSplitViewNavigationControllerVS_14NoStyleContext_: 0x7f883e819a00> 
(from <_TtGC7SwiftUIP13$7fff562fec9428DestinationHostingControllerVS_7AnyView_: 0x7f883e4169b0>) 
whose view is not in the window hierarchy.
```

I realize the error is saying I'm trying to present a view on top of another, which isn't even in the window view hierarchy yet. I've come across other questions that ask about similar things and the solution was to wait until you get notified that the view is on screen (via `viewDidAppear` and such). But I have some observations which make me think this is a different case:

- The error happens *only* when the `NavigationLink` leading to the detail view is inside a `List` (see code below). When outside of a `List` everything works fine.
- The error also happens only on an iPhone. On an iPhone target I get the error when the `NavigationLink` is inside a `List`, but everything works when it isn't. On an iPad target the eventual `fullScreenCover` works regardless of whether the `NavigationLink` was inside a `List` or not.

  - All of my work has been in the simulator so far, in case that matters.

Code that reproduces the issue is below. Note the commented out `List` container in `MainAppView`. If I run it as is in an iPhone, the intro view is visible. If I uncomment the `List` container, I get the error. I realize I'm missing something about the way the view hierarchy is modified when a `List` is involved, and it's somehow different when you're in different size classes. But I can't quite figure out what that is or where to learn about it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct MainAppView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
//            List {  // <-- Uncomment this line (and closing brace 3 lines down) to hit issue
                NavigationLink(destination: ComplicatedView()) {
                    Text("Go to complicated view")
                }
//            }
        }
    }
}

struct ComplicatedView: View {
    @State private var showingCover = true

    var body: some View {
        DetailsOfComplicatedView()
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showingCover, content: {
            TutorialView()
        })
    }
}

struct DetailsOfComplicatedView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Some nitty gritty details go here.")
            Text("But if it all goes right, it should immediately get covered up by a tutorial view. Does it?")
        }
    }
}

struct TutorialView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("I'd like to take a moment and explain this complicated view.")
            Button("OK") {
                // Do something to dismiss. But not relevant to the question.
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MainAppView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bit early, activate full screen on view appeared, like below (tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14)

```
struct ComplicatedView: View {
    @State private var showingCover = false

    var body: some View {
        DetailsOfComplicatedView()
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showingCover, content: {
            TutorialView()
        })
        .onAppear { self.showingCover = true }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Asperi; it works indeed. I'm curious though, why wouldn't the original code (i.e. without the `onAppear`) work on an iPhone when inside of a list? Every example of `fullScreenCover` I've seen makes it seem like it should. Is it just a new API being flaky?